# How to launch a browser from an Iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

Any idea how to launch an instance of Safari from an Iphone or Ipad application? But the case its that I would like to manipulate some aspects of the Safari window, for example I would like to launch it in Kiosk mode, without the addres bar.

I found something like openUrl but I am not sure if it is the best way and I can customize the windows properties etc...

Answer (score 49):

Do the same

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];

//Swift

> UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.init(string:
>   "https://www.google.com")!)

SFSafariViewController,
An object that provides a standard interface for browsing the web.

[check this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller)

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 10.0 this is deprecated,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
```

You need to use this instead to get the same old behavior,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"] options:[NSDictionary dictionary] completionHandler:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

`openURL` is the only (public) way to launch an instance of Safari, or of any other application.

Comment: I would like to know the NonPublic way :)

Comment: I don't know it, sorry. Don't forget that using non-public methods is a sure way to get your app rejected from the app store, if you're intending to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Each iOS app is sandboxed,meaning, it cannot interact with other apps. The only (if I'm not mistaken) way to communicate outside sandbox with system and other apps is trough [UIApplication sharedApplication].

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally I found a great solution and very simple :), in Interface builder there is an object called:  **Web View** , it offers the web browsing capabilities in a kiosk mode without need to use safari.

Answer (score 0):

for with query string

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/%s/%s","http://www.facebook.com","?opt=value"];  
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

for without query string

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```